# Azure ML - Read only error when adding file

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

So I am creating a simple pipeline to learn AML. I am creating with OutputFileDatasetConfig folders to contain the train and test files.

In the first step I am splitting the baseline dataset into train X and Y and test X and Y and writing them to this location - this is working.

In the second step, I am taking the train data and transforming it, creating a transformed data file. When trying to write it, using exactly the same method as before I am getting an error

"User program failed with OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '

Snippets from the second step

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--train_folder', dest='train_folder', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

X_train_path = os.path.join(args.train_folder, "X_train.txt")
X_train = np.loadtxt(X_train_path, delimiter=",")

## transformation code here returning X_train_transformed numpy array

run.log('X_train_transf', X_train_transformed.shape)
#this works

np.savetxt(
    os.path.join(args.train_folder,"X_train_transf.txt"),
    X_train_transformed,
    delimiter=",")
```

I tried to try different OutputFileDatasetConfig modes, but it does not seem like it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Error - "User program failed with OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file
> system: '

As error suggests, file has Read only permission, you do not have Write permission for same file.

Try

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/your/folder
```

Or

```
chmod -R 755 /path/to/your/folder
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this. The question is how between the first step and the second the  permissions were changed. Do these folders expect a single write only? Is it not advisable to continue modifying their contents?